# Array returns 2 different values for same index

Tags: php, arrays, variables, onclick, echo

I have the following PHP code:

```
$Directory = "somepath/somedirectory/";
$Files = glob($Directory . "*.jpg");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Files); $i++) {
    echo ('<img src="' . $Files[$i] . '"/>');
}
```

To what I get:

```
<img src="somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg"/>
<img src="somepath/somedirectory/01.jpg"/>
<img src="somepath/somedirectory/02.jpg"/>
//etc...
```

All good here.
But wen I had a onclick(), that is suppose to use the same variable "$Files[$i]", like so:

```
$Directory = "somepath/somedirectory/";
$Files = glob($Directory . "*.jpg");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Files); $i++) {
    echo ('<img src="' . $Files[$i] . '" onclick="ChangeImage("' . $Files[$i] . '")"/>');
}
```

I get:

```
<img 00.jpg")"="" somedirectory="" somepath=""  onclick="ChangeImage(" src="somepath/somedirectory//00.jpg">
<img 01.jpg")"="" somedirectory="" somepath=""  onclick="ChangeImage(" src="somepath/somedirectory//01.jpg">
//etc...
```

What is going on?
Why this result?

What I want is:

```
<img src="somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg" onclick=("somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg")/>
<img src="somepath/somedirectory/01.jpg" onclick=("somepath/somedirectory/01.jpg")/>
//etc...
```

Comment: `echo ("<img src="'` ... is this a typo?

Comment: You are mixing quote types. The StackOverflow syntax highlighter has picked it up as well, it is clearly showing you where the problem is. Hint: strings should be completely red.

Comment: I just can't figure out how this code would even run if that's not a typo. Wouldn't there be a syntax error and no output?

Comment: yes, it was a typo, I corrected it.
But the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution.

Firts of all, what I should have been looking for was:

```
onclick="ChangeImage('somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg')"
```

And not:

```
onclick="ChangeImage("somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg")"
```

So I ended up with this code:

```
echo ('<img src="' . $Files[$i] . '" onclick="ChangeImage(&#39;' . $Files[$i] . '&#39;)"/>');
```

And it now works grate.

Answer (score 3):

bad quoting, try this

```
echo '<img src="'.$Files[$i].'" onclick="ChangeImage("'.$Files[$i].'")"/>';
```

Comment: This does not work since this gives me:
    <img src="somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg" onclick=(somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg)/>

Wen I need:
    <img src="somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg" onclick=("somepath/somedirectory/00.jpg")/>

Notice the "" in the path of onclick().

Comment: just edited, with quotes

Comment: For some reason that does not work, I tryed it already, as you can see from my 1º post, thats what I was using and getting that strange result)

Comment: u've used different quotes

Comment: No I did'nt. Yours: onclick="ChangeImage("'.$Files[$i].'")

Mine: onclick="ChangeImage("' . $Files[$i] . '")

The only difference are the spaces to separate the variable.